# In new Outlook web mail, how to restrict the options are not opening in a new tab?

Tags: outlook.com

In the [new Outlook web mail](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-help-with-the-new-outlook-on-the-web-017014cd-2ad0-41ab-8473-6bd8c349d4f8), when clicking on the **Mail, Calendar, People** and **Tasks** options in the bottom of the page it is opening it in a new tab.

> [image: Options]

In previous Outlook versions, clicking on those options will open on the same page itself.

Is there a way to restrict in settings that not allowing to open the each options in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are open in a new tab issue was reported in [Outlook Uservoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/907141-the-new-outlook-on-the-web-office-365/suggestions/36708415-do-not-open-calendar-contacts-or-tasks-in-a-new-w#comments), and it was fixed recently.

Now clicking on those options, the option page is rendered on the same page itself.